# Keeping Bezier spiral curve handle tilt perpendicular to a specific axis

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

It's doesn't seem to matter if I use the curves "extra objects" to make the spiral or just create it on my own. I can't seem to find a way to keep tilt parallel to any one axis. Or make tilt uniform in any meaningful way without tilting each handle individually, which is a waste of time.

[image]

I'm using this spiral as a curve modifier. I have an object following this spiral curve path. I want to have some control over its orientation and deformation, which is why I'm not using the "follow path" constraint. I'd like to set the handle tilt uniform to a certain axis so the object stays level as it travels up the spiral.

The problem:

[image]

The final result will be a flow demonstration with arrows, very similar to this example I made in another project, but with a long spiral as shown above. I need to be able to control how the arrows rotate as they travel along the path.

[image]

Is there any way to keep tilt aligned to a specific axis so I can predict object rotation?

I've already tried:
• Setting the "mean tilt" number with all points selected
• Clearing tilt (my example image is what happens when you clear the tilt)
• Convert from curve > mesh > back to curve
• Tilt interpolation options
• Proportional editing while in tilt edit mode
• I need object deformation, so I will not be using path constraints

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I solved it! In the **Curve Properties** menu, **Twisting** should be set to **Z-up**.

This makes all handle tilts level to one axis, and from there, I can tilt them all together or one at a time to get my desired result.

[image]

And the final result, with no errant twisting or rotating:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think the closest thing you can do is 'Clear tilt'.

While in edit mode of the curve, select all curve points and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or choose the tool from the menu shown below:

[image]

However, on a spiral this does seem to still allow for some curvature to remain. But, on a spiral where all 'levels' of the spiral are the same you should be able to then tilt all the incorrect curve points at once with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to correct them all at the same time.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to mention that I already tried "clear tilt" as well. The tilt you see in my example above IS the resting tilt, or what happens if you clear the tilt.