# Curve Modifier Gives Unexpected Effects

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am having problems understating the curve modifier. I can usually get it to do what I want, but only after a lot of trial and error and often I plain do not understand why it seems to work in the way it does.

I attach a blend file. I am trying to make a bridge by having a segment of the bridge, a curve for it to follow and using the array and curve modifiers replicate it along the path. I have applied scale and rotation, and made sure both the bridge segment and the curve share an origin. Still it seems to give bizarre results.

In the attached file, when I turn on the curve modifier, the bridge segment flips on its side. I am completely stumped by this. Why is this happening?

[Example Blend File](http://www.toohey.co.uk/Bridge%20Scene%20Stack%20Exchange.blend)

Comment: you can fix it by changing the tilt angle or limiting it  see this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16523/keeping-bezier-spiral-curve-handle-tilt-perpendicular-to-a-specific-axis

Comment: Bingo. Thank you. I'm not very good with curves yet, the tilt angle is a new concept to me. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tilt of individual (or all) points on a curve can be adjusted by highlighting the relevant control points and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> followed by making the adjustment.

When you are using another object with a curve modifier this will adjust the orientation of that object as it follows the curve.